# Is the Silverlight Application class constructor called on the UI thread?

Tags: silverlight, constructor, windows-phone-7.1, ui-thread

In Silverlight for WP7, all UI elements are constructed on the UI Thread, and I've noticed that the Application class constructor also runs on the same thread. And the first UI element to be constructed (PhoneApplicationFrame) is constructed on the same thread.

So my question: is the Application class constructed on the UI Thread after that thread is determined? Or does the construction of that first UI element, PhoneApplicationFrame, determine that the current thread will be the UI thread?

Which is the chicken and which is the egg, if you will.

Or is it something else entirely?